# Google Apps Script CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES keep returning blank values. Is this enum deprecated or something's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a simple code with the purpose of:

1. Setup a formula on Column [x] referring to Column [n]
2. Copy the formula (on the same column) to cover all the rows with data on Column [n]
3. Copy back the result from Column[x] to Column [n] as value only using `CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES`

My code looks like this:

```
function Test() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var startingcell = ss.getActiveCell()
  ss.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate()
  var lastrow = ss.getActiveRange().getNumRows()

  // offset to create formula
  ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate()
  ss.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('IF(R[0]C1<>0,R[0]C1,12)')
    
  
  // set active range then copy down to cover all row with data on initial column
  ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, lastrow).activate()
  ss.getCurrentCell().copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false)

  // copy paste value back to initial column
  ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1, lastrow).activate();
  ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1, lastrow).copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
 

}
```

Let's just say my data is on Column A, with the `offset` I produce the formula on Column B, then tried to Copy-Paste Value back the result to Column A

But instead of the values, what I got in Column A is empty cells (the initial values got deleted)

Anything wrong with my code or the enum is deprecated?

Funny thing is when I use the enum `CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL` instead, I get the expected result where the content, in this case formula, is copied to Column A (of course the pasted formula wont run due to circular dependency)

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue and your goal, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

In your script, how about using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` as follows?

#### From:

```
// copy paste value back to initial column
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1, lastrow).activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1, lastrow).copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

#### To:

```
// copy paste value back to initial column
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, -1, lastrow).activate();
ss.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1, lastrow).copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

- From your situation of `Funny thing is when I use the enum CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL instead, I get the expected result where the content, in this case formula, is copied to Column A (of course the pasted formula wont run due to circular dependency)`, I thought that `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` might be required to be used.

#### Reference:

- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Comment: It works! I might have to use this `flush()` method regularly. Weird thing that several other codes I'm working on did not require this method and all the tasks within are fully executed in order. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @dDennis Thank you for replying. From `It works!`, I understood that your issue with this question was resolved. I'm glad about it. About `Weird thing that several other codes I'm working on did not require this method and all the tasks within are fully executed in order.`, although I'm not sure about the detailed situation, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your other scripts.